# Select pairs of rows in SQL (Should work in SQL Server 2008 and 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to pick pairs of rows from a table depending on values in one column.
This is my source table:

```
EntryID |   Code
-----------------
11      |   40
22      |   100  
23      |   80   
24      |   60   
35      |   90   
46      |   80   
47      |   30   
58      |   80   
69      |   20   
110     |   40
```

I need to extract only the rows where the code is 80 and the first row after the code 80. So this is the output I seek:

```
Code
------
80   
60   
80   
30   
80   
20
```

I can achieve this using cursors but my actual table has 1 million+ records. So cursors are definitely not an option.

I have so far done this:

```
declare @currentCode int
declare @rowPtr int
declare @code80row bit
declare @nextRowTaken bit
declare @T1 table (RowNum int, Code int)
declare @Final table (RowNum int, Code int)

set @rowPtr = 1
set @code80row = 0
set @nextRowTaken = 0

insert into @T1 select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EntryID desc) RowNum, Code from Codes
set @currentCode = (select code from @t1 where RowNum = @rowPtr)
while @currentCode > 0
begin
    if @currentCode = 80
    begin
        set @code80row = 1
        set @nextRowTaken = 0
        insert into @Final(RowNum, Code) values (@rowPtr, @currentCode)
    end
    else if (@code80row = 1 and @nextRowTaken = 0)
    begin
        set @code80row = 0
        set @nextRowTaken = 1
        insert into @Final(RowNum, Code) values (@rowPtr, @currentCode)
    end
    set @rowPtr = @rowPtr + 1
    set @currentCode = (select code from @t1 where RowNum = @rowPtr)
end
select * from @Final
```

Is there a better way to get this result?

EDIT:
Following @Serg's reply below, before he added the very last line, I tried this also.... This may help someone with different needs:

```
;with cte as (
    select Row_Number() over (order by EntryID) RowNum, entryid, Code from Codes
)
select ft.RowNum, st.RowNum, ft.entryid, st.entryid, ft.Code, st.Code
from cte as ft join cte as st
on ft.code = 80 and ft.RowNum = st.RowNum-1
```

which gives:

```
RowNum |RowNum |entryid |entryid |Code |Code
--------------------------------------------
3      |4      |23      |24      |80   |60
6      |7      |46      |47      |80   |30
8      |9      |58      |69      |80   |20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 2008 and no lead/lag

```
with cte as (
    select rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EntryID desc), EntryID, Code 
    from Codes
)
select t2.*
from cte c1 
cross apply ( 
      select EntryID, Code 
      from cte c2 
      where c1.rn between c2.rn and c2.rn+1
) t2
where c1.Code=80;
```

Comment: Good eye, didnt saw the `2008` there. But you need add the `80` condition

Comment: Corrected. Thanks @Juan

Comment: I made a small change to match OP request. Check here http://rextester.com/MSIG81332

Comment: @Juan, your addition is quit resonable. OP hasn't requested order explicitly, but i thing it was really implyed.

Comment: Not only that. If you change demo to older version will return  `[prev , 80]`, now return `[80, next]` as OP sample show

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the lag function to see the prior value of a field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(Code) OVER (ORDER BY EntryID) AS LAST_CODE
  FROM tablename 
) AS T
WHERE Code = 80 OR LAST_CODE = 80
```

Fairly sure you can use it in a where on sql-server but I don't have time to test right now and I know that code will work.

Comment: Nice @JuanCarlosOropeza that is helpful!

Comment: And yes, you need a sub query, and just realize **cant** use the windows function in a `where`

Comment: @Hogan, I need to execute this in SqlServer2008 and SqlServer2012. Lead and Lag work only in 2012 :(

Comment: @KSK in cases where you need a query work in different version is better indicate it on the question. Other wise we think you over extend with the tags.

Comment: just federate from the 2012 server :D

Comment: Great answer @Hogan. Worked flawlessly in my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you current and next:

```
SELECT EntryID , 
    Code, 
    LAG(Code, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY EntryID) AS NextCode 
FROM Codes 
WHERE Code = 80
ORDER BY EntryID


EntryID |   Code | NextCode
---------------------
23      |   80   | 60
46      |   80   | 30
58      |   80   | 20
```

Comment: Doesn't LEAD give you next and LAG give you prior?

Comment: @Jonathan, I need to execute this in SqlServer2008 and SqlServer2012. Lead and Lag work only in 2012 :(

Comment: Why are using a database that is past it's end of life? You need to get off that ASAP.

Comment: @JonathanAllen we're already living in a zombie apocalypse. The solution was deployed when server 2008 was the best that money could buy.